# How pass a list of my vagrant virtual machines to my haproxy.cfg using chef templates?

Tags: chef-infra, haproxy

I have two vagrant virtual machines each with their private ip addresses. I want to be able to pass the virtual machines as a list of servers in a chef recipe using templates.

[haproxy.cfg.erb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1RYW.png)

That is my haproxy.cfg.erb without the default and global parts. Each of my vagrant vms have a private ip asdefined in the vagrant file. If I try to curl ip of loadbalacer it throws 503 error

## 503 Service Unavailable

No server is available to handle this request.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Do you mean how to make an array of strings in Ruby?

Comment: frontend http-in
  bind *:80
  default_backend http-backend

backend http-backend
  mode http
  stats enable
  stats uri /haproxy?stats
  balance roundrobin
  option httpclose
  option forwardfor
  http-check expect status 200

  <% @backend_nodes.each do |node| %>
  server <%= node.name %> <%= node.ipaddress %>:80 check
  <% end %>

Comment: That is my haproxy.cfg.erb...Each of my vagrant nodes has a private ip and so does my loadbalancer. Now when I try to curl my loadbalancer ip it throws503 error

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel?  Have you tried using the haproxy community cookbook?  It can manage server lists based on node tags and other attributes.  https://github.com/hw-cookbooks/haproxy

Comment: My vagrant VMs have private ips. Somehow I cant get the correct ips in my templates, node.ipaddress is the ohai address

Comment: Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

If private IP assigned can be seen through with ifconfig in vagrant VM:-

```
[vagrant@default-centos ~]$ ifconfig
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fec3:36f0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 08:00:27:c3:36:f0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 37365  bytes 48794691 (46.5 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 6475  bytes 549951 (537.0 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.13.101  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.13.255
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe1a:2ec5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 08:00:27:1a:2e:c5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 17  bytes 1948 (1.9 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 35  bytes 5197 (5.0 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Then the assigned private ipaddress can be accessed by OHAI, like:-

```
node[:network][:interfaces][:enp0s8][:addresses].detect{|k,v| v[:family] == "inet" }.first
```